# Finding closest zip code using neo4j

Tags: neo4j

We wanted find closest zip code for a given zip code. This is one of the simple usecase we wanted to address from a number of other use cases.

We come across Neo4j and other graph db which seem to be addressing the use cases what we had, I am new to Neo4j and exploring to further. However, i stuck at a point how to represent the nodes and veritces in neo4j to solve the above use cases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you define closeness of zip codes? I mean apart from neo4j or any technology, what makes zip code A closer to zip code B than to zip code C?

Comment: Please describe in detail what your model looks like and what you try to do.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by closest ZIP code and for which country you want to find that.

Usually ZIP codes or post codes represents hierarchy structure. Also they could be attached to specific post office. Some countries provide GPS coordinates for each ZIP code and base on that information you can find closest ZIP code.

You can represent hierarchy structure in Neo4j as a tree and find closest ZIP code thru that tree.

Or you can represent ZIP codes in [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) structure in Neo4j.

Another options is to use [Neo4j Spatial library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial).